# Compare two columns to create a new column in Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame that has 2 columns, I am trying to create a new column using the other two columns with the when otherwise operation.

```
df_newcol = df.withColumn("Flag", when(col("a") <= lit(ratio1) | col("b") <= lit(ratio1), 1).otherwise(2))
```

But this throws an error

```
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

I have used when and otherwise previously with one column, while using it with multiple columns do we have to write the logic differently.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an operator precedence issue, make sure you put comparison operators in parenthesis when the comparison is mixed with logical operators such as `&` and `|`, with which being fixed, you don't even need `lit`, a scalar should work as well:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]], ['a', 'b'])
```

Both of the following should work:

```
df.withColumn('flag', F.when((F.col("a") <= F.lit(2)) | (F.col("b") <= F.lit(2)), 1).otherwise(2)).show()
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|   1|
|  2|  3|   1|
|  3|  4|   2|
+---+---+----+

df.withColumn('flag', F.when((F.col("a") <= 2) | (F.col("b") <= 2), 1).otherwise(2)).show()
+---+---+----+
|  a|  b|flag|
+---+---+----+
|  1|  2|   1|
|  2|  3|   1|
|  3|  4|   2|
+---+---+----+
```

Comment: can this logic be done with columns from different dataframes? Say, column a in df1 and column b in df2, and flag in df1. @Psidom